# can't read utf8 character from json in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, utf-8

when i have the english character in my json file it's printing the read json in array, but when i have tibetan character(utf8) it's printing null. i am pasting my json and xcode code. please help. this code is what i am trying  from [core data tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

```
        int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {
            // Create the managed object context
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

            // Custom code here...
            // Save the managed object context
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
                exit(1);
            }
            NSError* err = nil;
            NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tsikzoe" ofType:@"json"];

            NSDictionary* tsikzoe = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]options:kNilOptions error:&err];
 NSLog(@"Imported tsikzoe: %@",[tsikzoe objectForKey:@"wordDef"]);


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the JSON

```
[{"id":1,"dictionaryType":1,"word":"༼༡༠༠༦༽ སྲོང་བཙན་ཆོས་ཀྱི་རྗེ་བོ་ཡབ་ཡུམ་གསུམ།","wordDef":"རྒྱལ་པོ་སྲུང་བཙན་སྒམ་པོ། བལ་བཟའ་ཁྲི་བཙུན། རྒྱ་བཟའ་ཀོང་ཇོ་བཅས་གསུམ་ལ་ཟེར།","dateSubmitted":"2012-08-19 00:00:00","author":2,"authorName":"དུང་དཀར་ཚིག་མཛོད།"},
  {"id":2,"dictionaryType":1,"word":"༼༡༠༤༠༽ བསོ།","wordDef":"བསོ་བསོ་ཞེས་པའི་སྒྲའི་ཁྱད་པར་གྱི་མིང༌།","dateSubmitted":"2012-08-19 00:00:00","author":2,"authorName":"དུང་དཀར་ཚིག་མཛོད།"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary* tsikzoe = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

Your JASON is an array in this case, so you will need to access one of the two elements in this array, which would be a dictionary.

A dictionary JSON will have this format

```
{
"employees": [    //right here! 
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

An Array JSON will have this format

```
{
[    //notice the difference. 
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Comment: dude i tried with array as well but no luck, in both cases when i use contents as english it works
        NSArray* tsikzoe = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]options:kNilOptions error:&err];
       
        NSLog(@"Imported tsikzoe: %@",tsikzoe);
it's giving out put


2012-11-29 11:12:49.384 tsikzoeMig[48217:303] Imported tsikzoe: (null)

don't you think it's some thing to do with encoding

Comment: try this one to ensure it's encoded with UTF8: NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];